# datepicker simple event creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

All I want to do is use 5 text-boxes, a calender and a button to create an event on a date-picker calender.

Here is the format

[image]

I have read all about the .setDate() and .getDate() but I cannot get them to work.  I have no experience with plugins only simple html and javascript.  What is the datepicker object called and why does everyones code no have a name for their functions?

Anyone with experience with this plugin should be able to do this is in 5 seconds

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery &amp; jQueryUI Base - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.7/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.highlight > a {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_inset-hard_55_ffeb80_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% bottom #FFEB80;
    color: #363636;
    border: 1px solid #FFDE2E;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var equip = document.getElementById('equipment').value;
var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
var surface = document.getElementById('surface').value;
var orderNumber = document.getElementById('orderNumber').value;
var responsible = document.getElementById('responsible').value;


var events = [ 
    { Title: "Equipment: " + equip + "\nSize: " + size + dated +
    "\nRequired on Surface: " + surface + "\nWork Order Number: " + orderNumber + "\nResponsible: " + responsible, Date: new Date("05/13/2013") }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("02/25/2011") }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2011") }
];


$("div").datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var result = [true, '', null];
        var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

        while (i < events.length && !event) {
            date = events[i].Date;

            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                event = events[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (event) {
            alert(event.Title);
        }
    }
});

});//]]>



var dated = $( "div.selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );

function alerter(form) {alert (form.size.value)}
function dog () {div.setDate("+2d");}


function submit(form){
var equip1 = form.equipment.value;
var size1 = form.size.value;
var surface1 = form.surface.value;
var orderNumber1 = form.orderNumber.value;
var responsible1 = form.responsible.value;
var inputDate1 = form.inputDate.value

var events = [ 
    { Title: "Equipment: " + equip1 + "\nSize: " + size1  +
    "\nRequired on Surface: " + surface1 + "\nWork Order Number: " + orderNumber1 + "\nResponsible: " + responsible1, Date: new Date(inputDate1) }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("05/25/2013") }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2011") }
];
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <FORM>
    Equipment: <input type='text' id='equipment' /> <br />
    Size: <input type='text' id='size' /> <br />
    Required on Surface: <input type='checkbox' id='surface' /> <br />
    Work Order Number: <input type='text' id='orderNumber' /> <br />
    Responsible: <input type='text' id='responsible' /> <br />

    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="alerter(this.form)">Add Lowering Event</button><br>
   </FORM>
</body>


</html>
```

Edited code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery &amp; jQueryUI Base - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.7/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.highlight > a {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_inset-hard_55_ffeb80_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% bottom #FFEB80;
    color: #363636;
    border: 1px solid #FFDE2E;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var equip = document.getElementById('equipment').value;
var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
var surface = document.getElementById('surface').value;
var orderNumber = document.getElementById('orderNumber').value;
var responsible = document.getElementById('responsible').value;
var date = document.getElementById('dateds').value

var events = [ 
    { Title: "Equipment: " + equip + "\nSize: " + size + date +
    "\nRequired on Surface: " + surface + "\nWork Order Number: " + orderNumber + "\nResponsible: " + responsible, Date: new Date(date) }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("02/25/2011") }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2011") }
];


$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var result = [true, '', null];
        var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

        while (i < events.length && !event) {
            date = events[i].Date;

            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                event = events[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (event) {
            alert(event.Title);
        }
    }
});

});//]]>



var dated = $("#datepicker").datepicker( "getDate" );

function alerter() {alert (dated)}
function dog () {div.setDate("+2d");}


function submit(form){
var equip1 = form.equipment.value;
var size1 = form.size.value;
var surface1 = form.surface.value;
var orderNumber1 = form.orderNumber.value;
var responsible1 = form.responsible.value;
var inputDate1 = form.inputDate.value

var events = [ 
    { Title: "Equipment: " + equip1 + "\nSize: " + size1  +
    "\nRequired on Surface: " + surface1 + "\nWork Order Number: " + orderNumber1 + "\nResponsible: " + responsible1, Date: new Date(inputDate1) }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("05/25/2013") }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2011") }
];
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <FORM>
    Equipment: <input type='text' id='equipment' /> <br />
    Size: <input type='text' id='size' /> <br />
    Required on Surface: <input type='checkbox' id='surface' /> <br />
    Work Order Number: <input type='text' id='orderNumber' /> <br />
    Responsible: <input type='text' id='responsible' /> <br />
    Date: <input type="text" id="dateds" /></p>

    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="alerter()">Add Lowering Event</button><br>
   </FORM>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I think the datepicker has to be applied to a text (or date) input field, not a DIV.

Comment: @Barmar - See http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline. "Display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an overlay. Simply call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input."

Comment: Why are you including 2 versions each of `jQuery` and `jQuery UI`? Also a `normalize.css` is traditionally loaded first, as it is a type of reset stylesheet.

Comment: Cause I'm a noob lol, which one should? I use I deleted the UI and moved normalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("div").datepicker` and `$("div.selector").datepicker` should both be `$("#datepicker").datepicker`. The first would attach a datepicker to every DIV on your page, the second doesn't work because you don't have a DIV with class `selector`.

Normally a datepicker is attached to an `<input>` element in the form, so when you submit the form the selected date will be submitted. Since you're putting it in a DIV, you could add an `<input type="hidden">` element to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date">
```

and add the following option to the datepicker:

```
altField: "date",
```

Using named versus anonymous functions is mainly a stylistic choice. If a short function is only used in one place, such as the `onSelect` option or an AJAX callback, it's common to put it inline as an anonymous function.

Comment: When i switch $("div").datepicker with $("#datepicker") my calender disappears. And switching $("div.selector") still gives me undefined whenever i call code like this    var dated =       $("#datepicker").datepicker( "getDate" );     function alerter() {alert (dated)}     <button type="button" onclick="alerter()">Add Lowering Event</button><br>

Comment: I am sorry, I am really bad at this, I am not comfortable with html. my class was in high school which was long ago.  I do not know what you mean by adding a <input type="hidden"> as I do not understand how onSelect will link to the hidden input and allow me to extract the date.

Comment: You still need `.datepicker(...)` after the selector, I fixed my answer. `getDate` will return undefined if the user hasn't selected a date yet, unless you set a default date.

Comment: Thanks for you help I need to attend a meeting now no time to analyze completely, what you are saying makes sence

Comment: Your assignment to `dated` happens when the page is first loaded, and never gets updated when the user selects something from the datepicker.

Comment: OP should simply use the [altField option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) which automatically binds the `datepicker` to an input.

Comment: Awesome it worked now when I hit refresh in IE it saves the date into the calender, now I just need to get the submit working and storing a new value into the system every time it is hit.

Comment: The alt-field option with the comma does not allow my calender to compile if I switch it to a ; it doesn't but does not link the function submit(form) to the datepicker

Comment: You only need the comma if it's in the middle of other options, if it's the last option you don't need it. Some browsers allow an extraneous comma at the end of an object, some don't.